# temperature from a molecular point of view

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature

The electric fan increases the velocity and hence the kinetic energy of the molecules in the air. this would mean that the temperature has increased. What's wrong with a conclusion? I want you to solve the conflict based on a statistical physics argument

Comment: This must have been asked before. The fan makes you feel cool because it moves the air your body has warmed up away, therefore making your body constantly in contact with air colder than the body.

Comment: What conflict? Electric fan consumes energy, so it does lead to increase of temperature of the air eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The electric fan increases the velocity and hence the kinetic energy
>   of the molecules in the air. this would mean that the temperature has
>   increased.

I think that there is a bit of a problem here. Kinetic energy is not quite the same as thermal energy and temperature. Thermal energy and temperature is a measure of *random*, thermal motion of atoms or molecules in an object. When your electric fan blows air through a room, it imparts kinetic energy to that mass of air molecules which are now all moving in the same direction, but it doesn't raise their thermal energy because their random motion with respect to each other is not changed. If, on the other hand, you start a bonfire in your room, then a lot of heat energy is created that, when transferred to the surrounding air, does increase their random motion with respect to each other. In this case the mass of air would have high thermal energy or temperature but little or no kinetic energy.

I think that a somewhat tricky tripping point is that one could argue that thermal energy is kinetic energy, too, since after all the individual air molecules in a hot air mass are randomly moving at high speeds and therefore have high individual kinetic energies, right? So if one looks at that mass of air from a microscopic viewpoint, one could say that all that motion is "kinetic energy" motion. That's true, IF you stay with a microscopic viewpoint. However, when we speak of thermal energies and temperatures, we are necessarily going to a macroscopic viewpoint in which we distinguish between (1) the net motion of all the atoms or molecules of an object in some direction and (2) the random motion of all those atoms and molecules with respect to each other. We then call type (1) motion "kinetic energy" and type (2) motion "thermal energy". Why do we make this distinction? Because it makes the analysis easier. Type (1) motion can be analyzed using the classical laws of motion, and type (2) motion can be analyzed using the concepts of temperature, entropy, and other parameters of thermodynamics.

Comment: then, how can I find a resolution on above conflict based on a statistical physics argument?

Comment: @begin - The resolution is to recognize that from the thermodynamic, macroscopic viewpoint that increasing the kinetic energy of the air with a fan is not increasing its thermal energy or temperature. Thermal energy is associated with random motion of the air molecules, not with the uniform motion of all the air molecules in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

> "An electric fan is generating wind (a flow of air). when you sit in the wind, you feel cool. ... The electric fan increases the velocity and hence the kinetic energy of the molecules in the air. this would mean that the temperature has increased. What's wrong with these two conclusion?"

1) You feel cool when a fan blows air on you because it removes the warm air that stays close to your body and is heated by your body.

If you are wet the water on you absorbs heat to evaporate and so it lowers the temperature of your skin significantly.

If the temperature in the room is above 36, like 42 for example, you do not feel cool at all when the fans blows air on you. The effect quite is unpleasant in a dry environment like a desert, even at night. If it happens to drive a car through the desert at night an the temperature is 40-42 it is not a good idea to open the window because you will get nothing but a hot air current.

2) "*For typical air at room conditions, the average molecule is moving at about 500 m/s*", [Source](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/SpeedofSound.html). The fan can add 10 m/s to the average speed which is insignificant. You will not be able to feel any increase in temperature.